# AVAudioRecorder halts recording when screen goes to sleep. Is there a way to keep recording even when screen locks?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am building a sound recorder with Swift/Xcode. The recorder works fine when the screen is unlocked. However, while recording is in progress if I leave the device idle, the screen locks automatically (As it should) but it seems the app also halts and pause the recording process until the screen is unlocked again (then it resumes recording).
I would like my app to keep recording even when the screen is locked. Is there any way to do so?
This is what the recording part of my code looks like:

```
                audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: filename, settings: settings)
                audioRecorder.delegate = self
                try recordingSession.setCategory(.multiRoute)
                audioRecorder.record()
```

Comment: And have you configured the background `audio` mode?

Comment: Did you enable the "Audio, Airplay and PiP" background mode? I believe that's required. (I also believe that recording without showing any visual indication is a terrible idea).

Comment: @Gereon, your suggestion worked! "Audio, Airplay and PiP"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XCode project settings, under "Signing & Capabilities", add Background Modes, and check "Audio, AirPlay, and Picture in Picture"